# How to publish build artifacts to external organisation using Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an ASP web application that I have building in an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline. That is all fine.

I want an external organisation to be able to define their own Azure DevOps Release Pipeline to consume the build artifacts produced by our Build Pipeline. I need the access of that external organisation to be restricted with some sort of credentials (i.e. I don't want the project to be public to everyone). The external organisation should be able to deploy the latest version.

I thought this would be a relatively simple process using only Azure tools (particularly with reference to Feeds), but have tried a number of different approaches based on the documentation but all have failed. I don't want to publish to GitHub - I just want to keep everything inside Azure. I have tried using Universal Packages with Feeds, but the Release Pipeline can only pull a specific version from the feed rather than LATEST.

Does anyone have any recommended approaches I should take?

Answer (score 0):

There is `Latest` option in the feed of your Release Pipeline:

[image]